# How can I use the Objective-C APIs listed in Script Editor's Library?

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript, applescript-objc

According to Script Editor, there are Objective-C APIs that can be used instead of AppleScript or JavaScript. Here's an example, from Terminal:

[image: script editor library]

How do I actually use these? Presumably I'd need headers that defined these enums, classes, and methods. Where are those?

*Presumably*, given those headers, I could also use Swift via bridging, which would be nice, although not mandatory.

Comment: Do you want to use Objective-C in ScriptEditor or do you want to use the dictionary in an Objective-C/Swift app?

Comment: That documentation's for use with macOS's ScriptingBridge framework, which is crap. AppleScript may be a lousy language, but it's the only (nominally) supported option that speaks Apple events right. The best way to use Apple events from ObjC/Swift is to [call into AppleScript via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html). ASOC makes AppleScript script objects and handlers appear as regular Cocoa classes/instances and methods to the rest of your program.

Comment: ScriptingBridge is ok for small things like Next Track in iTunes or Close Window in Safari. It depends on the quality and simplicity of the dictionary.

Comment: @Wilelke: As you say, SB may work for for trivial tasks, but it breaks on a lot of tasks that work perfectly in AppleScript and [other bridges](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/status.html) that speak AEs right.  Its documentation, user support, and Swift integration are also poor, and Apple haven't fixed or maintained it in years. OP can try it if they want, but soon as they hit any problems I recommend they bail for AppleScript+ASOC, as that at least works and has the documentation and user community to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Script Editor can only show AppleScript dictionaries.

You find the Objective-C API in the [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/)

AppleScriptObjC does not support Swift syntax.